# How to stop or deal with spam server connections

Tags: server

I looked online and can't seem to find too many similar stories, which is surprising.

I rented a server from a provider, and I run my server software on there. My iOS app connects to it. It's been up for over a month with no issues, and gets about dozens of connections a day.

Starting about 30 hours ago, someone began to connect to it every 2 seconds. Always same IP. I doubt he leaved his phone on for 30 hours? And my app has only <100 daily users, so I have no competitors who would gain from this.

I finally blocked him from my server using iptable. From the software engineering side, what is the common practice for preventing these kinds of things? Am I supposed to keep track from the server side and refuse to accept repeated connections? Do I use some sort of login/handshake, or what do I do?

To clarify, I do not use http or apache. I wrote a server based on BSD sockets using a custom protocol over TCP. I also have a crypto hash and would terminate a connection if the message doesn't hash correctly.

EDIT: I did a count in my connection log. 3 IPs connected totaling 10,000 times over the last 30 hours. 2 of them have since stopped. All from a tiny country in Asia which I won't name.

Comment: For such things do not modify or put constraints on system related things like iptable. Implement blocking of suspicious request as part of server logic. You can use `Memcache` to record the number of request from particular IP and take decision depending upon the threshold limits  of incoming request within a period of time say 1 hour. Also use TTL on Memcache keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement some sort of antirobot in your application:

- Drop incoming connection if there are already >= N established connections from the same IP address.
- Drop incoming connection if total number of connections from this IP address for last 1, 5, and 30 minutes exceeds predefined thresholds (yes, you will need to keep track of number of connections made from each IP address).

More sophisticated antirobots used in high-load environments would also have means of detecting and blocking not only single IP addresses, but also whole ranges of IP addresses (networks). And also it would be better not to drop connections blindly but to redirect clients to captcha.

Anyway, there is no perfect solution to distinguish between robot and normal client: either you drop some good clients, or you allow some robots to sift through your antirobot.

Comment: Thanks gudok. I just searched and saw that it's best to block at the network stack (using iptables I presume?). Because in the server software, I can't get the peer address until after I call BSD accept. But iptables requires root/sudo and I'd like to not run as root. At what point do you recommend dropping a connection?